How to get user input in Flask and use it as a variable?
I need to make a flask server that allows the user to enter an input then collects and saves that input. In another program I import my flask program to retrieve the variable and print it, but the program does not fetch the user's input.
I have my flask code (app.py):
from flask import Flask, request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

user_input = None

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    global user_input
    if request.method == "POST":
        # Store the input in the global variable
        user_input = request.form.get("user_input")
        return f"Stored input: {user_input}"
    return render_template("index.html")


def get_user_input():
    return user_input


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000, debug=True)


I have my program to print input code:
import app
if __name__ == "__main__":
    user_input = app.get_user_input()

    if user_input:
        print(f"Accessed user input from app.py: {user_input}")
    else:
        print("No input has been stored yet.")


I have my index.html code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>User Input</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST">
        <label for="user_input">Enter something:</label>
        <input type="text" id="user_input" name="user_input">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>


You should either (1) save the user input to somewhere on disk (ex. text file, DB), then let your program read from that same location, OR (2) expose an API/endpoint on your Flask app that returns user_input, then make your program call that API/endpoint to get the value. Accessing it "as a variable" is not the right way.

Also, Are global variables thread-safe in Flask? How do I share data between requests?

Try this, maybe work delete user_input = None and define user_input global in there
